# VS Code user snippet convert filename(kebab case) to snake case

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

My file name: `company-news-model.js`

I want it to become `company_news`;

Answer (score 0):

If you must have it in a snippet, try this:

```
"filePath to snake": {
  "prefix": "2Snake",
  "body": [

    "${TM_FILENAME_BASE/-([^-]*)(?=-)|(-.*)$/${1:+_}$1/gm}"

     // gm regex flags are both necessary
     // just put a ; at the end (before the closing quote) if you want one there
    
  ]
}
```

It will work on any length fileName, like a-b-c-d.js, etc.

Using your example file: `company-news-model.js`

`TM_FILENAME_BASE` : `company-news-model`

`-([^-]*)(?=-)` : matches `-news` only, capture group 1

`(-.*)$` : match the end of the name, `-model` in group 2, which we won't use in the replacement

Note that `company` is never matched, you don't need to as long as it is acceptable to have it in the final result, which it is.

Replacement transform :

`${1:+_}` : this means **if** there is a group 1, insert an `_`
`$1` : insert group 1

So `company` falls through since it is never matched, followed by an `_` and group 1.  Then because it is a global regex, add anymore `_` and group 1's that are found.

> Note that files like `company-news-model.component.js` will be converted to `company_news` as I think would be expected.

---

A more robust approach can convert **any case fileName** to kebab-case - but it would be a keybinding and not a snippet.  And you will need the extension [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#overview) (written by me).

Make this keybinding (in your `keybindings.json`):

```
 {
  "key": "alt+s",                  // whatever keybinding you want 
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    // inserted at the cursor(s), if cursor is not in or against a word
    "replace": "${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
    "postCommands": ["editor.action.transformToKebabcase", "cancelSelection"]
  },
}
```

The `fileBasenameNoExtension` is inserted, selected, and then the command `editor.action.transformToKebabcase` is run on it.

Comment: Is it possible to convert the filename in kebab-case from any other case?

Comment: @MightyCoderX Yes, if a keybinding is okay (instead of a snippet).  See the info added to the end of the answer.